# LAMP server configuration to access virtual hosted website from same network

Tags: networking, ubuntu, virtual-host, lamp

I am trying to access on my LAMP server website a name-based virtual host—named `homeapp`—from other computers and a tablet.

- My LAMP server Ubuntu IP is `192.168.2.10`.
- My Laravel website is virtual hosted by named, `homeapp`.
- I can access to my IP `192.168.2.10` but problem is it just opened `localhost` index page.
- How can I access to my virtual hosted websites from same network?

Comment: Hi Jake, yes. I just edited. Could you suggest me how to setup? I googling and got some said, dns_server needed, some suggest to use pfsense. I am just reading about pfsense. Could you give me some useful link to learn. Thank advanced.

Comment: Hi Jake, Laravel angular app is a bit complicated to setup under localhost rather than virtualhost. I don't want to change route system of my app and laravel encourage to use virtualhost. :-( And I think virtualhost is a better practice than locahost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add an entry to your host file. Then you'll be able to use a DNS name to access it. The following command will do what you want:

```
echo "192.168.2.10 homeapp" >> /etc/hosts
```

You'll need to do this on each client that you'll be accessing this site from. For Windows clients it will be very similar:

```
ECHO "192.168.2.10 homeapp" >> %System32%\Drivers\etc\hosts
```

**Tablets**

Yes, your tablets and smart phones will also (generally) have a host file but you'll need a rooted device in order to edit it. Once that's done, all of the common Tablet OSes have several terminal apps available. Another option would be to use the [Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html) to edit it. Just copy the host file to the device and use the following command (assuming that the device is at F: and you've put your host file there):

```
adb push F:\hosts /system/etc/
```

This will put the host file on the device shared drive over the stock file.

A better tutorial is on [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/140576/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-on-android-and-block-web-sites/)

**NOTE**: If you have an [internal DNS server](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/dns-configuration.html) then you can (and should) just add an 'A' record for it instead.

Comment: Thank krowe, it is a good solution. It solve my problem. But as said, I can't change un-rooted tablet hosts file. Anyway It can be accessed from another computer. I will try to setup internet DNS server on my Ubuntu. Anyway thank.